# Why am I unable to assign value to a private variable in c++ class?

Tags: c++, class, private

```
using namespace std;

class Student{
    public:
        Student(int test)
        {
            if(test == key)
            {cout << "A student is being verified with a correct key: "<< test << endl;}
        }
        private:
        int key= 705;
};



int main()
{
    int testkey;
    cout << "Enter key for Bob: ";
    cin >> testkey;

    Student bob(testkey);
}
```

So I tried to run it but it says that C++ cannot assign key a value "Error making key static".
I have no idea what it means :(

Comment: @LuchianGrigore But it works on my GCC, what's wrong with this code?

Comment: I'm really new to programming. Can you please point out where the syntax went wrong or what should be done to make it right?

I believe you get what I was trying to do. It's not working on codeblocks

Comment: Need to enable C++11 to make `int key= 705;` work in class declaration.

Comment: "Error making key static" is not the error message you got. There must have been more words than that.

Comment: @user2477112 I do. Apparently you didn't get that I was implying you should learn from a book, not just dish out code and expect it to work, without knowing the basics.

Comment: The syntax is correct, but it requires C++11 support.

Answer (score 1):

[In class member initializers](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#member-init) is a C++11 feature, otherwise you have to initialize it in the constructor.

```
class Student {
public:
    Student(int test)
    : key(705) {
   // ^^^^^^^^
        if(test == key)
            cout << "A student is being verified with a correct key: "<< test << endl;
    }

private:
    int key;
};
```

Comment: You can initialize non-static data members at the point of declaration, just not in C++03.